# vim how to comma align

Tags: vim, alignment

I have a bunch of code of the form:

```
someVector.push_back(Foo("some name", 1.0, 3.1415926);
someVector.push_back(Foo("different length name", 89.0, 2.717);
... 20 more entries
```

I want sufficient space to be inserted so that my code is comma aligned, i.e. the "1.0," 's comma and the "89.0"'s comma are aligned -- is there builtins to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Vim's [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin.  It does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

With the Align plugin it's just simple: select the lines in visual mode and type <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>